# As a beginner, what should I look for when buying my first synthesizer?

Tags: synthesizer, synthesis

There are countless options out there and it is very easy for a beginner to feel overwhelmed. Which features should I be looking for? Which are the most important characteristics? How can the options be classified?

Comment: What would you like to do with it? The most important characteristics are situational. You might want portability over sound quality, or sound quality over a broad palate. Maybe you want to be able to recreate an orchestra, or maybe you just want classic 70s or 80s synth sounds. As it stands, this seems really too broad. It's like asking what to look for in a guitar without specifying acoustic, electric, classical, or genre.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm not looking for product recommendations, but an overview for a beginner. You could carve the first part of your comment as a very interesting section of an answer. Similar questions have been asked before with very good reception and ended up being very useful. Search for "what to look for first" to see some examples. I'm asking this one specifically because I saw the other, more specific, question getting closed and wanted a similar one that is on scope.

Comment: I did the search. The entire first page of results are all far more specific than your question. All of them state some combination of intended use, price range, specific category, etc. The word "synthesizer" itself is so broad it could include a complicated tape machine, software plugin, capictively coupled oscillator, wave table module, doctored Commodore 64 computer, and so on. The possibilities are manifold.

Comment: @ToddWilcox What would make this specific enough? What to look for when buying my first analog subtractive synthesizer? A separate question should be asked for every synthesis type? For every genre? I think this question can be easily answered in its current form and you might be exaggerating a little bit on the broadness. It's just meant to be an overview for the beginner that asks this very common question. "There are many types of synths, the most common are this, and that, and so on".

Comment: What about what are the most popular types of synthesis? Or what to look for if I want to learn how to use synthesizers? Or why are the most famous synthesizers so popular?

Comment: @ToddWilcox But those questions have nothing to do with this one. This is supposed to aid a beginner looking to buy a synth. You are over thinking it. There are countless types of electric guitars but the question on this site had good answers regardless because you don't have to focus on every single little variable, an overview of the most popular and common is more than enough. I know there's a lot more variety in synths (that's why it is so easy to feel overwhelmed in the first place), but the same principle applies.

Comment: @ToddWilcox And that's probably how the answer should be carved as: "if you are a beginner you should focus on the simpler and most common stuff like subtractive, fm, wavetable, your options are these and these because..." The beginner part is what makes the scope much more smaller than you think it is.

Comment: First thing I thought of was modular, subtractive, analogue synths. But you mention FM, wavetable and additive which are very different sounds and (I guess) techniques.  So the beginner should have some idea on the sound differences, at least.

Comment: Many beginning musicians may confuse the term synthesizer with or use it synonymously with keyboard instruments that can serve various functions similar to a true synthesizer - such as Sampler Keyboard, MIDI Controller Keyboard, Workstation Keyboard, Arranger Keyboard, Portable Digital Keyboard, Digital Piano and others. Should the answer deal only with true synthesizers or should a discussion of the other type keyboard instruments/input devices be a part of the answer?  Should the answer be limited to keyboard controlled synthesizers or should all types of input devices be explored?

Comment: I don't think this is off topic; we have had similar questions before. Like 'what to look out for when buying a used piano' etc. I think it's a good question

Comment: have you thought of downloading some softsynths? There are lots of free and shareware/trialware ones. These would give you some idea of what to look for.

Comment: I'd go with Dave's suggestion - it's a _helluva_ lot less expensive, and you get to find out what does what without too much strain, just, perhaps, the cost of an inexpensive MIDI controller (which you can continue using as you buy hardware). Consider also programmes like PureData and Csound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With little experience and without clear vision of requirements, this probably will not be the last synthesizer you ever buy. In other words, you are buying the exploration device.

For such a device, I would suggest to set the budget limit and select the synthesizer that has as many various features available as possible. Then you will be able to try all of them and be much more sure about your requirements later.

The quality probably does not matter as much, as after exploration (and discovering you really like) you can buy a long-term model that is strong in features you like the most.